# Comments in Stata and Mata: Do file editor vs command prompt

Tags: comments, stata

I typically work in another text editor and simply copy and paste my work into Stata's command prompt. However, I have noticed a difference between the way the command prompt and the `do` file editor handle comments.

The code below reproduces the things I have discovered:

```
mata
//test comment
/* test comment 2 */
end

//test comment 3
*test comment 4
/* test comment 5*/
```

When run from the `do` file editor, the code runs without issue.

But when I run it after copying and pasting into the command prompt, I receive a number of `r(3000)` errors in `mata` and `r(199)` errors in Stata.

The sole exception is that the `*` comments in regular Stata work fine in both interfaces.

I also see that the `//` comment in `mata` gives an "expression invalid" error message along with the `r(3000)` notification, but I only receive the `r(3000)` message when I use the `/* text */` comment. In regular Stata, both comment types that are not `*` give "/ is not a valid command name" messages along with the `r(199)`.

My main question is:

- What is the reason behind this difference? Is there anything I can do to suppress these errors?

Also, this is something like a red flag for me:

- Are there other behaviors that differ when I run things via the command prompt rather than the `do` file editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following *Technical Note* from the [16th Stata manual about Do-files](https://www.stata.com/manuals/u16.pdf) explains:

> *"...The /* */, //, and /// comment indicators can be used in do-files and ado-files only; you may not use them interactively. You can, however, use the ‘*’ comment indicator interactively*..."

So there is nothing surprising here. You can easily prevent errors like these by following the conventions. Just read [the relevant section](https://www.stata.com/manuals/u16.pdf#u16.1.2) of the aforementioned manual for more details.

Only StataCorp knows for sure, but such differences probably arise from how Stata interprets the code internally when this is parsed from a `do` file or the command prompt.

See the following post for another (unrelated) example of an inconsistent behaviour:

- [Stata axis labels off-center when broken over multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563533/stata-axis-labels-off-center-when-broken-over-multiple-lines/49864549#49864549)

Personally, after using Stata extensively for years, i have not noticed any other major differences when running code from `do` files and interactively.

Comment: This is helpful. It appears that there is no mata equivalent to the * comment indicator then, which is a shame. From the [mata manual](https://www.stata.com/manuals/m-2comments.pdf), it says "Comments may appear in do-files and ado-files; they are not allowed interactively"

Comment: Mata's rules about statement completion imply that `*` meaning multiplication could be the first element of a continuation line. Enter Mata and enter `(2` and `* 2)` on successive lines. Allowing that was, I think, the rationale for disallowing `*` as a comment indicator.